# Traversing the DOM with querySelector

Tags: html, css, dom

I'm using the statement `document.querySelector("[data-testid='people-menu'] div:nth-child(4)")` in the console to give me the below HTML snippet:

```
<div>
   <span class="jss1">
      <div class="jss2">
         <p class="jss3">Owner</p>
      </div>
   </span>
   <div class="jss4">
      <div class="5" title="User Title">
         <p class="jss6">UT</p>
      </div>
      <div class="jss7">
         <p class="jss82">User Title</p>
         <span class="jss9">Project Manager</span>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to extend the statement in the console to extract the title `"User Title"` but can't figure out what combination of `nth-child` or `nextSibling` (or something else) to use. The closest I've gotten is:

`document.querySelector("[data-testid='people-menu'] div:nth-child(4) span:nth-child(1)")`

which gives me the span with class `jss1`.

I expected `document.querySelector("[data-testid='people-menu'] div:nth-child(4) span:nth-child(1).nextSibling")` to give me the `div` with class `jss4`, but it returns `null`.

I can't use class selectors because those are generated dynamically at build.

Comment: What are you expecting `div:nth-child(4)` to be? None of the `<div>`s you’ve shown is the fourth child of any parent, except maybe the surrounding `<div>`, but your question doesn’t include this context (the `[data-testid='people-menu']` element is also not shown). `.nextSibling` is a generic class selector; it doesn’t get you the next sibling. _`nextElementSibling`_ is a property of each Element. Use the dev tools: right-click → Inspect element; then right-click on the DOM node → Copy as … → CSS selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just add [title] onto your querySelector?

document.querySelector("[data-testid='people-menu'] div:nth-child(4) [title]")

You can then get whatever you are looking for from that section? This is assuming title will be unique attribute in this section of html